# Const correctness warnings c++

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-warnings

Does anyone know of any warnings that C++ compilers provide that help to enforce const correctness? For instance, it would be nice to have a warning produced by any C++ method that contains a non-const parameter that is never modified inside of the method. I see that there is a gnu compiler warning called -Wsuggest-attribute=const; however, when I use this flag I get an error saying that it is not recognized. Any ideas why?

Comment: "const correctness" does not really have much to do with method arguments or local variables. cppcheck can emit style warnings on class methods that can just as well be made const.

Comment: `-Wsuggest-attribute` is about GCC-specific function attributes, not about const correctness. `__attribute__((const))` is somewhat similar to `constexpr`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think such a warning exists, mostly because it would be useless. Just because a parameter is not modified inside the call, doesn't mean it should be made `const` just for the sake of it.

Think of `virtual` functions. Perhaps the designer of the base class, although not modifying the parameter in the base class, wants to leave it up to an extending class whether or not to modify that parameter.

Also, think of large applications, where modifying interfaces or API's or whatever costs a lot. You might not need to modify the parameter now, but intend to do so in the future. You're not going to make it `const` now, and force a full rebuild and probably risk errors in the future when you remove the `const`.

Comment: I see your point; however, I still think this would be useful as a warning (perhaps not an error). Furthermore, it seems that there is a flag for the gnu compiler called -Wsuggest-attribute=const; but my g++ compiler doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Not a feature that I would ever leave running on a compiler, but would be nice to turn on every now and then to review suggestions. If you know a function isn't going to modify a variable, it's a good practice to make it const as it allows const variables to be passed in.

Comment: [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/) has this feature (unnecessary `mut`), and it's something I miss coming back to C++ and trying to make sure APIs and local variables are immutable by default.

Answer (score 5):

```
-Wsuggest-attribute=const
```

This analysis requires option

```
-fipa-pure-const
```

which is enabled by default at

```
-O
```

and higher

Answer (score 4):

Careful, a `const` parameter like this one:

```
void myFunc(int const param);
```

does *not* belong to the interface. It belongs to the local scope of the function *implementation*. In fact, this function:

```
int inc(int const param) { return param+1; }
```

may be declared as

```
int inc(int param);
```

It is not a violation of the const correctness paradigm to claim the right to modify a variable but not actually do it.

If you are worried about `const_cast` you can either not use it in the first place or simply `grep` for it in your code base.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there are no such warnings. You just get errors if you try to change const declared parameters. This is because missing `const` declarations do not change the correctness of the code from the compilers point of view. But const correctness is important for the compiler to discover potential optimizations and it improves the readability of the code. It is a matter of professionalism. Especially when using references const correctness is a must. [I often refer to this.](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html)
The compiler itself takes const correctness very serious when operators (assignement, conversion, ...) come into play. A missing `const` here and the compiler refuses to use the operator because it makes a big difference if the given parameter may possibly be modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such warnings and I think they would be rather hard to implement in a compiler - that is, they would slow it down. Maybe some static analysis tools have such features (but I'm not aware of those either).

As per `Wsuggest-attribute=const`, that is a different thing. It will suggest to use a gcc-specific "function attribute `const`", which is, basically, a mathematical function, receiving only values (no pointers), not reading or changing any static/global state and returning only a value (no pointers). For further description, look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes